# perlで二次元配列の書き方について

Tags: perl, array

```
.#.#....
.#.#....
........
.....#.#
.......#
......#.
........
.......#
........
........
```

このような10行＊8列計80個セルの入力データ（仮にsample.txt）があります。
perlでこのsample.txtからデータを読み込んで、一行一列ずつ二次元配列に代入したいです。

つまり＠hairetu[i][j]の形で任意位置の要素を抽出することができるようにしたいです。
例：
@hairetu[1][1]は"#"が表示
@hairetu[3][2]は"."が表示

自分のコードは一行目は1つの要素として認識されてしまったので、うまくいかなかったです。
コードは以下となります。どういう風に書けばいいのか、プロな方教えて頂ければ幸いです。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @hairetu;
my $i = 0;

my $file = 'sample.txt';
open (IN, $file) or die "$!";

while (my $ = <IN>) {
   chomp($data);
   $hairetu[$i] = $data;
   $i = $i + 1
}

$length = @hairetu;
# print $length;
for( $i=0 ; $i<@hairetu ; ++$i )
{
   print $hairetu[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: http://perldoc.jp/docs/perl/5.22.1/perllol.pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while = <IN>`で読みとった行を`split`で分割(今回の場合は1文字ずつ)しながら"配列の配列"、の行に対して代入していけばよいかと思います。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file = "sample.txt";
my @AoA  = (); # 配列の配列(Array of Array)
my $i    = 0;

open(FH,"<$file") or die;

while( my $line = <FH> ) {
    chomp($line);

    # 読み取った行($line)の内容を
    # split(//,$line)で一文字ずつに分割し
    # "配列の配列"の$i行目に"配列"として代入
    $AoA[$i] = [ split(//,$line) ];

    $i++;
}

print "1x1: $AoA[1][1]\n";
print "3x2: $AoA[3][2]\n";
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。もう一つお聞きしたいですが、
全ての要素を循環して、"#""."の数を別々に統計したいとすると、この場合のfor文をどいう風に書けばいいのでしょうか、お手数をおかけします。

Answer (score 1):

別解として push を使う方法など。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

##use Data::Dumper;
my @hairetu;
my $file = 'sample.txt';

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "$file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  push @hairetu, [split//];
}

print $hairetu[1][1], "\n";
print $hairetu[3][2], "\n";
##print Dumper(@hairetu),
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。もう一つお聞きしたいですが、
全ての要素を循環して、"#""."の数を別々に統計したいとすると、この場合のfor文をどいう風に書けばいいのでしょうか、お手数をおかけします。